# File permissions; Should my www-folder content be owned by www-data?

Tags: php, security, permissions, webserver

This might be a noob question, but can't find an answer anywhere.

I have a problem, which [Another file permissions problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483832/another-file-permissions-problem) have helped me to ALMOST solve.

I have created a user in linux (**danny**) which has sudo access.
I have also created a new group which name ALSO is **danny**, and added the user **danny** to that group. **This group has sudo (root) access.**

I have all files and folders in my **www** folder owned by danny/danny group.

I have an image-upload code which is **php**. This code cannot upload images to a folder called "**images**" folder which is under the **www** folder, UNLESS I give the images folder **777** permissions.

So, I have followed the answer on the linked question, and have figured out that the user which the upload-script is run as is "**www-data**".

According to the answer on the link to the other question I posted, I need to add **www-data** to a group... But I am stuck here...

Which group should I add to? What should I do from here?

Any tips are appreciated.

Btw, here is some info about www-data and danny

```
  id www-data:
  uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)
  id danny
  uid=1000(danny) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)
```

Thanks and if you need more input, just let me know...

Comment: You have selected by far the worst answer,  as in you will be hacked if you use this advice.  You should change this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Actually, your problem is that you need the user **www-data** to have write-access to the **images** folder.

And you probably want user **danny** to have full access to the folder as well.

**EDIT: Additional word of warning:**
having files writeable by your webserver is always a **security risk**. Be sure to check the files that are written, and make sure people can't upload or change code.
Summary:
 * Don't let your webserver run scripts that are writeable, or in a writeable folder.
So make sure only the images/ folder is writeable, and doublecheck that everything that is written, is actually an image!

Either:

1. Set www-data as owner of the folder,
   and chmod u+rwx www.
2. Set www-data
   as part of a group X, and change the
   owner of the folder to X, and chmod
   g+rwx www.
3. Set the folder
       world-writeable on your server (in
       some cases, an acceptable solution
       too, but less secure).

Comment: Finally got it to work, I followed solution 1 you proposed above. One last thing, the permissions are now 765 on the image_folder. This is good and safe I hope? BUT, how can I restrict people from viewing my file in the browsers? (what I mean is, for instance, you type www.domain.com/images, then all folders show up)

Comment: @Camran: To prevent apache from showing directory listings, use .htaccess to turn off the "Indexes" Option.  (`Options -Indexes`)

Comment: -1 a web app should not have write access to its own web root,  and under no condition should the folder be world writable or readable.  This is massive mistake and it really bothers me.

Comment: 760 permissions better (though danny won't be able to access that folder).
The .htaccess idea is good too.

Comment: @LatinSuD I think even that is too loose, read my post I explain why

Comment: World readable is rarely an issue, other than for files which contain things like database passwords. Ditto for executable. (You're already letting random users on the internet execute the code via their browsers...) With respect to web-accessible/web-executable files, write access is the only thing that normally needs to be restricted. 644 or 755 is usually the way to go.

Comment: @Dave Sherohman I strongly disagree,  if another process (like mysql's `load_file()`) or another user can read your php config to obtain a clear text username/password,  a read .htacess password.  Hacked :).

Comment: @The Rook: You're disagreeing with something I didn't say. To quote myself: "World readable is rarely an issue, **other than for files which contain things like database passwords**."  The php/.htaccess files you mention are clearly such files and should, therefore, not be world-readable according to my earlier comment.

Comment: He's disagreeing with something I didn't say either ;) Let me edit the response a bit to add a word of warning to the quick-and-dirty readers.

Comment: @Konerak Don't give anyone anything,  setting the web root as world writable is serious mistake,  my -1 stays.  chmod 500 or 550,  no one should have write access,   its not needed unless you need a folder for cache or upload.

Comment: @Dave Sherohman Your right,  i was lazy and i didn't read your entire post.   You have a good post,  you know what you are doing.

Comment: This is literately the worst advice you could possibly give.  Please delete this mistake!

Comment: @Rook: if I was wrong, I'd like to know. But in the original question (and I quote): **I have an image-upload code which is php. This code cannot upload images to a folder called "images" folder which is under the www folder, UNLESS I give the images folder 777 permissions.** -> The web application NEEDS to upload images to this images folder. So the images folder, IMHO, needs to be writable by the web application user. I can't find how your answer solves the "users need to upload images in my application" problem, but if you show me, I might even delete this answer.

Answer (score 21):

In general, **NO**, your content should **not** be owned by www-data.  The **only** content which should be owned by www-data are the specific files that you need web applications to be able to modify and specific directories that they need to be able to create or delete files in.  The rest should not be owned (or writable) by www-data because every file that www-data can write to is a file that an attacker who compromises your web server (including any scripts or web apps that it is running) will be able to replace with whatever malicious data he may choose.

It is especially important that www-data **not** own or be able to write to **any** executable file (e.g., scripts, flash files, documents in Word or other formats with macro capabilities, etc.) because replacing them with malicious executables would provide an easy way to attack users' computers or the web server itself.

Comment: So do I get it right that the suggestion at http://askubuntu.com/a/9411/12938 is actually a poor one?

Comment: @texnic - The answer you linked is fine. It says to set your user account as the owner and www-data as the group on the web directories, and to set their permissions to 0755, which gives www-data permissions to read and execute, but not to write. These settings are consistent with what I said in my answer here.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks. I'm slowly grasping the whole idea.

Comment: It's a 13 year old thread, but I wish I could upvote this answer by +1000000.  There are so many posts everywhere _incorrectly_ saying that web content should be owned by www-data.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm rewriting this answer after 13 years because it was insecure.)

You could create a new group, that is shared between danny and web server. Then assign folders to that group. Let's call it `danny-web`.

```
groupadd danny-web
```

Add dany and www-data users to the new group.

```
usermod -a -G danny-web danny
usermod -a -G danny-web www-data
```

Now you only need to assign folders to group `danny-web`, and give permissions to the group.

```
chown danny:danny-web myweb
chmod 750 myweb
chmod 770 myweb/uploads
```

This is a folder where www-data only needs read-only access:

```
-rwxr-x---  danny    danny-web   myweb
```

This is a folder where www-data needs read-write access:

```
-rwxrwx---  danny    danny-web   myweb/uploads
```

Comment: Any thoughts on the comment I posted on Koneraks question?

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that all danny's files would be potentially accessible to the internet if the webserver is compromised?  This seems to be a bad idea to me.